# How to practise Zazen so that it leads to Satori?

Tags: zen, meditation-zazen

Currently I practise Zazen as I have read from books i.e 'Just sitting doing nothing'. I keep an erect sitting posture, back straight and eyes closed.
This hasen't led me anywhere.

So I am asking the official way to practise Zazen and Zen in general so as to lead one to Stori.

Comment: I recommend reading The Three Pillars of Zen

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has.  You just don't know where it's led you.  Keep at it and you'll find your way out of the bag eventually.

(Official answer - get a teacher.  You can't practice Zen by yourself.)